# Why does no one care that kids are stomping aquatic animals in the pool in "Finding Dory"?

Tags: plot-explanation, finding-dory

In Finding Dory (2016), kids are stomping aquatic animals in the pool but no one cares, even though adults are present there.

[image]

This black ink is released by an octopus to frighten the kids.

Why does no one care about the coarse behavior of the kids?

Comment: Are they stomping, or touching?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Interactive kid exhibits and 'touch tanks' are quite common in aquariums** and you can even safely pet stingrays and sharks in some of them. The facility depicted in *Finding Dory*  was based on the [Monterey Bay Aquarium](http://www.slashfilm.com/finding-dory-real-life-inspiration/) which includes such tanks and even lets you [feel an octopus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCA8-mr5b5c) sometimes. It might have been exaggerated a little, but kids are definitely allowed to touch some of the marine life. Here are some examples of such exhibits:

[image]
[image]
[image]